# How can I normalize an array in python? Getting an error: "Found array with dim 3. the normalize function expected <= 2."

Tags: python, preprocessor, normalize

I have an array looks like:

```
X_t = array([[2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5],
   [2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5],
   [2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5],
   ...,
   [2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5],
   [2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5],
   [2600,    3,  253, ...,    4,    4,    5]])
```

with shape (6524, 31)
When I am trying to normalize it using several normalizing code, it is giving me same error, "Found array with dim 3. the normalize function expected <= 2."
But the shape of X_t is 2D.

The code that I used are:
1.

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

 norm1 = X_t / np.linalg.norm(X_t)
 norm2 = normalize(X_t[:,np.newaxis], axis=0).ravel()
 print (np.all(norm1 == norm2))
```

2.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize([X_t])
```

Can anyone tell me, what is the problem here?

Comment: Why are you adding another axis?

Comment: Where did I add another axis? In code 2 there is no new axis! It’s still giving the same error!

Comment: You added square brackets around `X_t`.